# Getting the last modified date of a file in Java

Tags: java, file, browser, date

I'm making a basic file browser and want to get the last modified date of each file in a directory. How might I do this? I already have the name and type of each file (all stored in an array), but need the last modified date, too.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As in the javadocs for [`java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

`new File("/path/to/file").lastModified()`

Answer (score 41):

**Since Java 7**, you can use [`java.nio.file.Files.getLastModifiedTime(Path path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getLastModifiedTime(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)):

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\1.txt");

FileTime fileTime;
try {
    fileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path);
    printFileTime(fileTime);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Cannot get the last modified time - " + e);
}
```

where `printFileName` can look like this:

```
private static void printFileTime(FileTime fileTime) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(fileTime.toMillis()));
}
```

**Output**:

```
10/06/2016 - 11:02:41
```

Comment: The answer is correct and well explained, but please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Instead, since Java 8, use `FileTime.toInstant()`, convert the `Instant` to `ZonedDateTime` and either just print it or format it using a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to achieve the result: Explained the returns types etc. Hope it helps you.

```
File file = new File("\home\noname\abc.txt");
String fileName = file.getAbsoluteFile().getName(); 
// gets you the filename: abc.txt
long fileLastModifiedDate = file.lastModified(); 
// returns last modified date in long format 
System.out.println(fileLastModifiedDate); 
// e.g. 1644199079746
Date date = new Date(fileLastModifiedDate); 
// create date object which accept long
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); 
// this is the format, you can change as you prefer: 2022-02-07 09:57:59
String myDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date); 
// accepts date and returns String value
System.out.println("Last Modified Date of the FileName:" + fileName + "\t" + myDate); 
// abc.txt and 2022-02-07 09:57:59
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.