# Collect metadata from file java

Tags: java, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the last modified date of a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363197/getting-the-last-modified-date-of-a-file-in-java)

Is there a way to get file metadata like "date modified" in java?

Comment: Did you even look for yourself? It takes next to no time to google 'java file metadata' and the first result looks relatively promising.

Comment: @Anthony: And if you google "collect java file metadata", the first result is *this question*.

Answer (score 3):

The [`java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class has several methods that could be of interest to you, e.g. [`lastModified()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

[`java.io.File#lastModified()`.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29)

```
File f = new File(...);
if (f.exists())
{
    System.out.println(new Date(f.lastModified()));
}
```