# How to convert the file last modified timestamp to a date?

Tags: java, date

How do I convert [`File#lastModified()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) to a real date? The format is not really important.

Comment: Reopened, because this question is about the conversion to java.util.Date.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
Date d = new Date(file.lastModified());
```

`lastModified()` returns the milliseconds since 1970-01-01, and the `Date` class stores its time also in the same way. The `Date(long)` constructor takes these milliseconds, and initializes the `Date` with it.

Comment: When using java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime, toMillis() has to be called

Comment: `lastModified() returns the milliseconds since 1970-01-01` using what timezone? I have an issue sending the date to a javascript running on the browser, and the date is one day greater than the server date.

Comment: @ps0604: I believe in the "current" timezone, which can be found with System.getProperty("user.timezone")

Answer (score 18):

Just you use the `SimpleDateFormat` class to convert long to date.
Only you execute code:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss").format(
    new Date(new File(filename).lastModified()) 
);
```

Answer (score 6):

What you get is a long number representing the number of millis elapsed from Jan 1st, 1970. That's the standard way of representing dates.

try this:

```
java.util.Date myDate = new java.util.Date(theFile.lastModified());
```

and now you have a Date object at hand.

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to print that date in a cuter way.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the last modified timestamp, as described in [the duplicate of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363197/getting-the-last-modified-date-of-a-file-in-java)
2. Create a new `Date` object, or `Calendar` object. `new Date(timestamp)`. Or `Calendar.getInstance()` and then call `setTimeInMillis(timestamp)`. As the name suggests, the timestamp is actually a number of milliseconds (since Jan 1st 1970)
3. You can then format the date via `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`