# How to get ctime in java?

Tags: java, linux, ctime

I want to get ctime of a file in java.
ctime is change time ,can be get by using "ls -lc filename" in linux.
but how can I get it in java ? also I need to get it in java's FTP API.

Comment: Writing "to" instead of "2" just takes one more tap on your keyboard and makes you post better.

Comment: Is it [Getting the last modified date of a file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363197/getting-the-last-modified-date-of-a-file-in-java)?

Comment: Not lastModifiedTime(mtime), I need ctime in linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine file creation date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723838/determine-file-creation-date-in-java)

Comment: Oh, actually ctime is different from creation date (gets updated when file content changes): http://www.linux-faqs.info/general/difference-between-mtime-ctime-and-atime - Typical linux filesystems don't even have a creation date at all: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time

Comment: This is a great question.  I think the people who downvoted it just failed to understand it.  Takes all types to make the world go round, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You want to call

```
Files.getAttribute(path, "unix:ctime")
```

which will return the ctime (metadata changed time).  This only works in Unix/Linux systems of course.

I think it returns a `String` which you'll then have to parse if you want a date.  I can't try it out, of course, because my computer runs Windows.  I also don't know what time zone it will come back in.  So you'll have to experiment for yourself to see what comes back.

I've made this Community Wiki, and I invite anyone who *does* know the time zone and return format of this (or who wants to try it out on a Unix machine) to edit this post accordingly.

Comment: Note that you'll have to cast the return object to a `java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime`

Answer (score -1):

```
new File("C:\Users\username\Documents\filename").lastModified()
```

As given in the javadocs for 
[java.io.File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: Not lastModifiedTime(mtime), I need ctime in linux .

Comment: Do you mean this... http://superuser.com/questions/234158/show-both-ctime-and-atime-in-ls-output