# How to override default metadata.lastModifiedMillis() of Apache beam's FileIO with actual file's last modified time?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Use Case: I have to filter files based on the lastModifiedTime using Apache beam (Java)

My Code:

```
PCollection<String> readfile = pipeline
                .apply(FileIO.match().filepattern(path)
                        .continuously(Duration.standardSeconds(30), Watch.Growth.never()))
                .setCoder(MetadataCoderV2.of())
                .apply(Filter.by(metadata -> {
                    System.out.println("metadata: " + metadata.toString());
                    return (metadata.lastModifiedMillis()) > current;}))
                .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
                .apply(TextIO.readFiles());
```

Problem:
Even though I am using the MetadataCoderV2 coder, getting default value (0) for metadata.lastModifiedMillis() as below

```
Metadata{resourceId="fileName", sizeBytes=108, isReadSeekEfficient=true, lastModifiedMillis=0}
```

can anyone please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: If this does not work, how about get a list of the file names and write a `MapElements.via` (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/elementwise/mapelements/) through Java's own API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363197/getting-the-last-modified-date-of-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You should register the `MetadataCoderV2` earlier in the pipeline.
Also the `ReadableFileCoder` uses always `MetadataCoder` (v1) so you need to override it with a coder that handler Metadata v2.

```java
pipeline.getCoderRegistry().registerCoderForClass(MatchResult.Metadata.class,MetadataCoderV2.of());
pipeline.getCoderRegistry().registerCoderForClass(FileIO.ReadableFile.class, ReadableFileCoderV2.of());

pipeline.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern(path)
                        .continuously(Duration.standardSeconds(30), Watch.Growth.never()))
//rest of the pipeline
```

I opened a [PR](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/15510) for Beam to create `ReadableFileCoderv2`, but until that we will have to do it with some reflection since the FileIO.ReadableFile has no public method to initiate new instance of it.

```java
public class ReadableFileCoderv2 extends ReadableFileCoder {

    private static final ReadableFileCoderv2 INSTANCE = new ReadableFileCoderv2();

    public static ReadableFileCoderv2 of() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(FileIO.ReadableFile value, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        MetadataCoderV2.of().encode(value.getMetadata(), os);
        VarIntCoder.of().encode(value.getCompression().ordinal(), os);
    }

    @Override
    public FileIO.ReadableFile decode(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        MatchResult.Metadata metadata = MetadataCoderV2.of().decode(is);
        Compression compression = Compression.values()[VarIntCoder.of().decode(is)];
        try {
            FileIO.ReadableFile readableFile = (FileIO.ReadableFile) unsafe.allocateInstance(FileIO.ReadableFile.class);
            Field fieldMetadata = FileIO.ReadableFile.class.getDeclaredField("metadata");
            fieldMetadata.setAccessible(true);
            fieldMetadata.set(readableFile,metadata);
            Field fieldCompression = FileIO.ReadableFile.class.getDeclaredField("compression");
            fieldCompression.setAccessible(true);
            fieldCompression.set(readableFile,compression);
            return readableFile;
        } catch (InstantiationException | NoSuchFieldException |IllegalAccessException e) {
           return super.decode(is);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that the [PR](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/15510) in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69184379/4966331) has been merged, you can do:

```java
MetadataCoderV2 metadataCoder = MetadataCoderV2.of();
p.getCoderRegistry().registerCoderForClass(Metadata.class, metadataCoder);
p.getCoderRegistry().registerCoderForClass(FileIO.ReadableFile.class, ReadableFileCoder.of(metadataCoder));
```